Processing group of rows in same batch in Talend Open Studio for Data
I am using Talend studio coupled with Salesforce components and I am facing a case where I want to be able to load within the same batch
My data looks like below, where each row has this configuration



Id
data_1
RelatedToID




Id_1
My_data_1
1


Id_2
My_data_2
1


Id_3
My_data_3
1


Id_4
My_data_4
1


Id_5
My_data_5
2


Id_6
My_data_6
2


Id_7
My_data_7
3



and I would like to make sure that within the batches (usually 200 rows per batch) data are grouped by RelatedToId such as all the data with RelatedToId 1 are loaded in the same batch
all the data RelatedToId 2 are loaded within the same batch and so on.
I have around 300k rows and there is maximum 50 same RelatedToId. It doesn't matter if in the same batch I mixed data from RelatedtoId 1 and RelatedToId 2 for example I just want  to make sure I have all of them rregrouped in the same batch when loading

I have faced the same issue and the solution depends on your input (is a file like csv or something a database's table)
For example if it's a file (CSV) I usually do it like this :
First I get the value needed for the batch, in your case that would be 1, 2, 3
like this :

I use the tFlowToIterate to set the batch id (RelatedToId) and use the tFilterRow to get the rows associated with the ID

And store the rows in temp files named with the batch id

At the end you have (in your case) 3 files for each batch id 
On the other end if you use a database table you follow the same logic but replace the inputs and use SQL to filter only the rows you want
Hope this helps
